# Use anchors and :target for navigation. How to show first layer by default

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm trying to use anchors and CSS as navigation.

If user clicked on menu link, anchor target section should be displayed, but others should be hidden.

Here is the layout I'm using:

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1">Page #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2">Page #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page3">Page #3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
      <section id="page1">
        <h2>Page #1</h2>
      </section>
      <section id="page2">
        <h2>Page #2</h2>
      </section>
      <section id="page3">
        <h2>Page #3</h2>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Here is CSS I'm using:

```
    section:not(:target) {
      display: none;
    }
    section:target {
      display: block;
    }
```

Everything works perfect, but how i show first page by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the first page to `display:block;` and position it absolutelty with a lowwer z-index than the other pages.

This way, it is displayed by default and you can display the other ones over it with the `:target` pseudo selector.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Kbu3M/)**

*CSS :*

```
#page1 {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:76px;
    z-index:1
}
section:not(:target) {
    display: none;
}
section:target {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Great answer and fastest response... Thank you very much!

Comment: In my case, I've changed #page1 to section:first-child, to freely rearange sections and rename their id's.